# Applying for a UK visa outside the Schengen country that issued my visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I have a student visa issued by France as well as a residency permit. I need a visit visa to travel to the UK. Due to my location it would be much easier to apply at the Geneva embassy as it is only 30 minutes away. Is this possible and allowed?

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy you can apply in any country where UK entry clearance applications are accepted, provided you are present legally in that location.

Comment: In terms of the visa - would you then say yes to having a temporary visa?

Comment: @Megan I don’t understand your comment. It would also be useful if you stated your nationality